# Can anyone help me with sort fuctions written in Javascript to C# or explain me how these lines of code work

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm trying to transtate this Javascript function to C# method.

```
parametrize = (obj, join = false) ->
    arrayOfArrays = _.pairs(obj).sort()

    symbol = if join then '&' else ''

    sortedParams = ''
    _.each arrayOfArrays, (value) ->
      sortedParams += "#{_.first(value)}=#{_.last(value)}" + symbol

    return sortedParams
```

This functions is written base on these scenarios.

- parameters are sorted lexicographically by keys;
- parameters are joined in the format key=value;
- sig = MD5(parameters_value + session_secret_key);
- the sig value is changed to the lower case.

I would like to write this function in C# and because of lack of understanding of what javascript does. If anyone could help me explaining what Javascript functions do for example would be awesome.

Thank you :)

Comment: So you read the code (which is mostly like C#) and every time you hit something you didn't undertstand, you googled `javascript WORD_I_DIDNT_UNDERSTAND_HERE` and ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in terms of understanding the JavaScript, the method just combines an object containing key-value pairs and combines them into a single string with either a space between or an ampersand. I'm assuming this method is used to send parameters with a get or post request, or with spaces for command line arguments.

```
// method that accepts an object and a join boolean (false by default)
parametrize = (obj, join = false) ->

// sort the obects and store as an array
arrayOfArrays = _.pairs(obj).sort()

// decide which join character to use
symbol = if join then '&' else ''

// Create the variable to return
sortedParams = ''

// loop through each of the array rows 
_.each arrayOfArrays, (value) ->
  // add each row into the string and add the joining symbol
  sortedParams += "#{_.first(value)}=#{_.last(value)}" + symbol

// Once complete, return the created string
return sortedParams
```

As for the c# side of things, this is all fairly rudimentary stuff. A quick google on loops, strings (including concatenation) and methods will sort you out.